# Is the Panasonic Arc5 Shaver Kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

I would like to ask if these two shavers are kosher

1. amazon.com/dp/B00JWP8F3I
2. amazon.com/dp/B07XD5T8MN

Comment: Sorry, but as it says on this page, MY but does not offer personalized, professional advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your rabbi. Please ask your Rav.

Comment: There are  (perfectly Orthodox) communities that accept all electric shavers as kosher. Others forbid most electric shavers. This is one of the reasons MY does not offer psak. Your rabbi will know what's right for you

Answer (score 1):

[Machon Tzomet](https://www.zomet.org.il/eng/) has only [authorized](https://www.zomet.org.il/_Uploads/dbsAttachedFiles/panasonic.pdf) the following Panasonic models:

ES-LV6Q

ES-LV5C

ES-LV9C